# Unknown error in unstable data array

Tags: java-native-interface

This jni is working, but I may have a memory leak problem (i think),

can anyone help to release the memory below:

```
class arrayCls = env->GetObjectClass(Array1);
len11 = env -> GetArrayLength(Array1);
jintArray dim1= (jintArray) env->GetObjectArrayElement(Array1, 0);
len12 = env -> GetArrayLength(dim1);

localArray1= new jint*[len11];
for(jint i=0; i<len11; ++i){ 
    jintArray oneDim1=  (jintArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(Array1, i); 
    jint *element1=env->GetIntArrayElements(oneDim1, 0); 

    localArray1[i] = new jint[len12]; 
    for(jint j=0; j<len12; ++j) { 
        localArray1[i][j]= element1[j]; 
        env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(oneDim1, element1, 0); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You didn't free your `localarray1` or `localarray1[i]` in that code...

Comment: Can you show me how to do it.  i tried but i didn't go anywhere. Thx

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with them! You haven't posted the code that uses `localArray1` (all I see is you setting the values).

Comment: localArray1 is my matrix and it is used for further calculation.  I cannot clear it, but i want to release Array1, element1 etc. When I use localArray1, at some points, data in it be come unstable.  I suspect i may face memory leak problem.  What do you think?

Comment: Well, yes, you have a memory leak because you allocate them and never free them (unlike Java references, C arrays must be explicitly freed!)

Comment: But I need to finish all my computation before i can release them; However, during my computation I got crashed.  I used localArray1 as global data block currently. Any tip for me related to global and local data blocks so that I can stay away until my computation finished?

Comment: Here is my error if i release localArray1:error C2664: 'JNIEnv_::ReleaseIntArrayElements' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'jint **' to 'jintArray'

Answer (score 1):

This is the error:

```
for(jint j=0; j<len12; ++j) { 
    localArray1[i][j]= element1[j]; 
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(oneDim1, element1, 0); 
}
```

You must move

```
env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(oneDim1, element1, 0);
```

outside of the loop.  You should prefer GetIntArrayRegion() anyway, it would have avoided this error because it is stateless.